# poplib and email module will not reloop through a message if it has alread read it

Tags: python, email, poplib

I'm currently trying to write a script that gets messages from my gmail account but I'm noticing a problem. If poplib loops through a message in my inbox it will never loop through it again. Here is my code

```
import poplib, string, email

user = "jj@gmail.com"
password = "password"

message = ""
mail = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
mail.user(user)
mail.pass_(password)

iMessageCount = len(mail.list()[1])
message = ""
msg = mail.retr(iMessageCount)
str = string.join(msg[1], "\n")
frmMail = email.message_from_string(str)

for part in frmMail.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
        print part.get_payload()

mail.quit()
```

Every time I run this script it goes to the next newest email and just skips over the email that was shown last time it was run.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving a message with `mail.retr()` sets the *seen* flag for that message and so it will no longer be visible via `mail.list()` after `mail.quit()` has been called.

If you do not call `mail.quit()` your messages will remain unseen.

BTW, gmail supports IMAP which is generally better than POP3.